# Raspberry Pi: problem with external USB drive and USB modem

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, huawei-mobile-services, usb-drive

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Raspberry Pi OS Lite installed on an external USB drive (256GB SSD). After installation, I partitioned the drive and added an NTFS partition to store backups and share files. Currently, there are three partitions:

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sda           238.5G
├─sda1 vfat     512M /boot/firmware
├─sda2 ext4      32G /
└─sda3 ntfs     206G /mnt/usb`

Everything works well. However, when I connect a USB 3G modem (Huawei K4606), the system halts. I cannot execute any commands in the shell, and I receive the error: "Input/output error."

Attempting to boot with the USB modem connected results in the following errors:

`EXT4-fs error (device sda2): __ext4_get_inode_loc_noinmem:4605: inode #130071: block 524321: comm systemd-journal: unable to read itable block
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): __ext4_find_entry:1682: inode #8130: block 524321: comm systemd-udevd: reading directory lblock0`

How can I fix this issue?

I expect to use USB modem stick

Comment: I would guess the 3G modem is faulty and it's somehow interfering with the communication of other devices on your USB.  You might try seeing if you can get the 3G modem to work on other PC systems which are not based on a bootable USB stick.